# 2010 - List Permissions, Allow Add but restrict View

Tags: 2010, list

I made a Contact Us List on my Sharepoint because there is no Webpart for 2010.

People can Click a link in my mainpage, and they directly get to the add form of the list.

Now I want to restict the view of the list. So many people can add an item but are not allowed to view the list where these items are.

Is there any possibility to do that?

Or do you have a better idea of how to implement a Contact Us Form in SharePoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways for setting permission on what user can see/add in lists:

The easy one:

1. List settings -> Advanced settings
2. Checkmark on "Read items that were created by the user"
3. Checkmark on "Create items and edit items that were created by the user"

Then the user only can see their own items in the list (and can edit)

The second one:
Create a new permission level, then you have to set the right permission level (only add). Then add the permission level to the list.

Then users only can add items without viewing any of the list items.

Answer (score 1):

- The other way is to create a `Contact us` `application page` in your site and create a `web part` which accepts the contact us detail from the user and on submitting the request the data will be added to the `list`. And you can check the list.

Also you can have sorting on data to the last modified data. So you can get the latest request.

- The Other logic is add the link of NewForm.aspx page to your main page and add query string in the URL as "`http://serverurl/NewItem.aspx?source=<mainpage URL>`" This will redirect form to your main page on submitting the request.